# what do jQuery $'s mean

Tags: jquery

I'm confused by the different uses of the $ in jQuery.  Take for example:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#nav_lat").slicknav({prependTo:"#mobile_menu"});
});
```

The first $ could be replaced with "jQuery" and I realize that the second $ is being passed into the anonymous function but what does it mean?  And then the last $, what does that mean?

Comment: Your answer is here : http://www.authenticsociety.com/blog/JavaScript_DollarSign

Comment: It is just a reference to the jQuery object library itself so that you can access the properties and methods of the library. Just like Underscores uses _ to reference the library.

Comment: I'd also like to add that you can create your own jQuery object that doesn't conflict with other libraries with: `var j = jQuery.noConflict();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $ is just a function. It is actually an alias for the function called jQuery, so your code can be written like this with the exact same results:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#nav_lat").slicknav({prependTo:"#mobile_menu"});
});
```

The reason why you pass $ - as in `function($)` - is to avoid conflict in case where there are other libraries who use $ as the placeholder.

Comment: No, the reason someone would pass `jQuery` is because of other libraries that use the `$` (angular, for example).

Comment: Isn't that what i have said ?

Comment: No, you said *The reason why **you pass $ is to avoid conflict** in case where there are other libraries who use the same placeholder.*

Comment: as far as i know you pass `$` not `jQuery`

Comment: @OliverQueen You're describing conflicts. Angular  and jQuery would both expect the `$` to be available... hence conflict..?

Answer (score 1):

$ is short for JQuery. Sometimes when you are using multiple libraries you want to use JQuery instead because $ could be used by both libs.

But using only $ is faster when you know it will use the JQuery lib.

EDIT: Fun fact, you can write the ready function like this:

```
$(function(){
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it faster but rather *alot* less typing ;)